# ELSE running even when the IF part is true javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I did some looking around and I can't find an answer for this in Javascript. Most of the existing questions I've found were on other languages  (Python, C#, SQL, etc) and as a beginner, I'm not quite able to translate concepts between languages yet.

Anyway, what I have is an IF..ELSE statement and the ELSE part always runs even when the IF part evaluates to true and I thought it's supposed to do this:

```
if (condition) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition is true
} else { 
    block of code to be executed if the condition is false
}
```

Here's my code:

```
for(var key in Characters) {

    if (Characters[key][matchArr[0]] > 1 && Characters[key][matchArr[1]] > 1 && 
    Characters[key][matchArr[2]] > 1 && Characters[key][matchArr[3]] > 1 && 
    Characters[key][matchArr[4]] > 1) {

    console.log("if...stuff!")
    break; 

    } else {
    console.log("Else Stuff");
    }
}
```

I can verify that my first condition is true by simply running it in the console by itself and checking the output (which is true). If run without the `ELSE` part, I get the expected result `"if...stuff!"`. If run with the `ELSE` part, I get both.

It seems to have something to do with my condition rather than the how the loop is written or what I'm logging. If I write something like this, the `IF..ELSE` statement works just as I'd expect.

```
for(var key in Characters) {
    x = true;
    if (x === true) {
        console.log("if stuff");
        break;
    } else {
        console.log("else stuff");
        break;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my intended condition that it evaluates to `true` but in an `IF...ELSE` statement, it still runs the `ELSE` part.

```
Characters[key][matchArr[0]] > 1 && Characters[key][matchArr[1]] > 1 &&
Characters[key][matchArr[2]] > 1 && Characters[key][matchArr[3]] > 1 && 
Characters[key][matchArr[4]] > 1
```

**true**

Comment: What does console log give you for `Characters[key][matchArr[0]]` and such. Also, have you tried casting those as INTs?

Comment: perhaps for the the first `key` the condition is `false` ... and for the second `key` it is `true` - how about you `console.log(key)` before the if statement

Comment: For every iteration before the `if` condition is true the `else` will run. Once the `if` is true you then `break` out of the loop.

Comment: Jaromanda X and nnnnn I think you figured it out. I haven't tried anything yet this morning but now that you mention it, that makes sense. There would be a few `false` in there before the `true` and I didn't think about it that way. Learn something new every day and it's only 9am right now =) thanks

Comment: Goose If I console  Characters[key][matchArr[0]] it gives me a number (13 in this specific case).